# Meteor return value as string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

This is what I want to achieve.
I got two collections: `Questions` and `Answers`.
When a user answers a question, the answer will set in the `Answers` collection, and it passes the ID of the question with it.

I'm displaying a list with all the questions using this helper:

```
questions: function (){
    return Question.find({});
}
```

And this html:

```
<ol>
    {{#each questions}}
        <li>{{question}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

I want to display the answers that every user gave, below each question. I want to return the Question's ID as a string value, so I can do something like:

```
answers:function(){
    return Answer.find({question: <The ID of the question>});
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Yours,
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your `Question` collection has the following schema (simplified for brevity):

```
QuestionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Question"
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        label: "Category"
    }
});
```

and your `Answer` collection has

```
AnswerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        label: "Question"
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author"
    }
    question: {
        type: String,
        label: "Question"
    }
});
```

You can go about this by creating two template helpers where the first just returns an array of question documents and the second takes a single question id as parameter and returns a cursor of all of the answers with that question id:

```
Template.questions.helpers({
    questions: function(){        
        return Question.find({}).fetch();
    },
    answers: function(questionId){
        return Answer.find({question: questionId}).fetch();
    }
});
```

Next the template needs nested `{{#each}}` blocks with the first one iterating over the questions array and passing the answers to the next each as the parameter of the next helper.

```
<template name="questions">
    {{#each questions}}
        <h1>{{this.title}}</h1>
        <ol>
        {{#each answers this._id}}
            <li>{{text}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </ol>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. Hope it works

```
<ol>
{{#each questions}}
    <li>{{question}}</li>
    <li>{{answers}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ol>
```

In your js file.

```
answers:function(){
 id = this._id
return Answer.find({question:id});
}
```

According to your response from function you can use either with or each

Comment: I haven't got a 'Answer' value in my 'Question' field. Only a 'question' value in my 'answer' field.

Comment: i mean to call the answers function. So inside that you will get that question id